# Grid DataContextChanged was Not Fire while add item in source

Tags: c#, events, silverlight-5.0, datacontext

i have a grid in a usercontrol and assigned a datacontext is assigned

```
<Grid x:Name="GrdContainer" DataContext="{Binding FormAttributeMappings,Mode= TwoWay}"  DataContextChanged="GrdContainer_DataContextChanged" UseLayoutRounding="True">
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

private void GrdContainer_DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ......
}
```

when i am assign `List<FormAttributeMapping> FormAttributeMappings` as a Datacontext `GrdContainer_DataContextChanged` will  be fire but but when i am add some item in Grid datacontex source(`FormAttributeMappings.add(FormAttributeMapping)`)  `GrdContainer_DataContextChanged` not fire

Comment: Are you changing FormAttributeMappings property or other properties inside FormAttributeMappings? DataContextChanged fires only when FormAttriubeMappings property is changed

Comment: Grid datacontext is `List<FormAttributeMapping> FormAttributeMappings` . i am add one more FormAttributeMapping in to List

Answer (score 0):

Adding item to `List` won't fire `DataContextChanged` event, as it doesn't change `DataContext` property. To fire event you have to assing/change `FormAttributeMappings` property every time you add new item.

Better solution would be change type of `FormAttributeMappings' property to [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms668604.aspx) and create handler to [CollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms653375.aspx) event.